# Using a case statement in place of a logical operator

Tags: sql, oracle, case, logical-operators

I have a CASE statement like

```
CASE WHEN a AND b THEN c ELSE d END
```

I have a field in my table which contains logical operators like `AND`, `OR`

I want to use this field in stead of using the operator directly in the case statement above
so:

```
CASE WHEN a (CASE WHEN field.value = 'AND' THEN 'AND'OR 'OR' END) b THEN c ELSE d END
```

I tried introducing a user defined function as well and neither worked and I received a missing expression error.

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: @WillardSolutions, thanks for the edit. My apologies for the bad formatting

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is that a string is not an operator.  Perhaps the best you can do is:

```
 (CASE WHEN field.value = 'AND' AND (a AND b) THEN 'true'
       WHEN field.value = 'OR' AND (a OR b) THEN 'true'
  END) = 'true'
```

Or more simply as:

```
(field.value = 'AND' AND (a AND b)) OR
(field.value = 'OR' AND (a OR b))
```

However, I am suspicious of your overall data model.  Storing boolean operators in fields seems . . . unusual.

Comment: I finally followed this, but I am not entirely happy with it. I am going to check to see if there is a better way to handle my issue. Thanks for your suggestion though :)